# Creating the most efficient .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have been asked to clean up a htaccess file.

Here is the current code:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# This file was updated by Duplicator on 2018-05-01 07:23:35. See .htaccess.orig for the original .htaccess file.
# Please note that other plugins and resources write to this file. If the time-stamp above is different
# than the current time-stamp on the file system then another resource has updated this file.
# Duplicator only writes to this file once during the install process while running the installer.php file.

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, User-Agent, Content-Disposition"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Disposition"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} off
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

# RewriteEngine On 
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/com [NC]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

A couple points:

- In my SEO report it states 'No redirect or canonical to HTTPS homepage from HTTP version'.

  ~ even though I have a declaration in my header file that sets the canonical link, also the htaccess file currently redirects to the https version.

  ~ Apparently a 301 redirect will fix the above issue - from what I have read.

  ~ This is the reason I have been asked to look into this file.
- I wish for the site to redirect to the https version.
- I wish to keep the local caching of images.
- Feel free to remove commented out lines if this doesn't help

What is the best practice to achieve the results I currently am getting but so it uses a '301 redirect' with less clutter in the code?

Comment: Sorry, but do you hacve a _specific_ question here?

Comment: No apology necessary. What is the best practice to achieve the results I currently am getting but so it uses a '301 redirect' with less clutter in the code?

Comment: If you are currently redirected with a 302, then change `[R,L]` to `[R=301]`. Note: the `L` flag is not required with an external redirection anyway.

Comment: @arkascha - please put this into an answer so I can appreciate your answer... c:

Comment: @arkascha - at the top of the document there is a line 'RewriteOptions inherit' followed by commented out lines. Are you able to also inform me on wether this is still required?

Comment: That is something I cannot help with, since it depends on your local setup. It obviously depends on whether there are settings to be inherited, if not then you certainly could remove it. But I would generally advise against the use of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") unless really required, such global rewriting rules should be coded in the http servers host configuration instead. Much faster, easier to debug and maintain and less error prone.